# Django REST Framework - How to get current user in serializer

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have **TransactionSerializer**:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserHider(read_only=True)
    category_choices = tuple(UserCategories.objects.filter(user=**???**).values_list('category_name', flat=True))
    category = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=category_choices)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        payment_amount = self.validated_data['payment_amount']
        category = self.validated_data['category']
        organization = self.validated_data['organization']
        description = self.validated_data['description']
        return Transaction.objects.create(user=user, payment_amount=payment_amount, category=category,
                                          organization=organization, description=description)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('user', 'payment_amount', 'date', 'time', 'category', 'organization', 'description')
```

This totally does the job, however I need that instead of "???" the current user's ID, but I don't quite understand what basic ModelSerializer method I can use so as not to damage anything, but at the same time get the current user as a variable in order to substitute it later in the filtering place (in this case, categories are filtered if I put some specific user ID which is already registered, then on the **DRF** form, when creating an object, I get a drop-down list with categories specific only to my user)?

I have already tried to do this through the **get_user()** method, and also tried to create a variable inherited from another serializer, which defines just the user ID, but I received various kinds of errors.

Comment: Can you please be more clear with this section, ` instead of "???" the current user was substituted, or rather his ID`

Comment: If i will put for example 1 like that: .filter(user=1) - i'll get the same result as i expected (all the categories, that "attached" to user)

Answer (score -1):

```
UserCategories.objects.filter(user=user.id)
```

I guess this is what you want?? your current user id

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand how to get current user's instance, i mean how to get user.id part first of all

Comment: I think you will not be able to get the user id. You can only validate against it